# select blocks forever in helloworld type program

Tags: sockets, select

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    const char* host = "www.google.com";
    portno = 80;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR connecting");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("connected\n");

    const char* GET = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n\n";
    n = write(sock, GET, strlen(GET));
    printf("writen %i to %i\n", n, sock);

    fd_set RS;
    FD_ZERO(&RS);
    FD_SET(sock, &RS);

/*
    if uncommented, this code always works
    while (true) {
        char ch;
        recv(sock, &ch, 1, 0);
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
*/

    int ret = select(1, &RS, 0, 0, 0);// but this will block forecer

    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &RS)) {
        char ch;
        int count = recv(sock, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (count >= 0) {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This very simple example will block on `select()`. If you try to read with `recv()` without using `select()` first, it will read successfully, so the data is ready. Why the `select()` blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is classical, wrong first argument to select():

instead of

```
 select(1, &RS, 0, 0, 0);
```

use

```
 select(sock + 1, &RS, 0, 0, 0);
```